# Passing values between classes in tkinter

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

My problem is that I want my code to take an entry from the user, 
then the value that the user entered will be displayed on the toplevel page pf the previous class.
I have searched quite a bit but none of the solution worked for me.
So could any one of you generously tell me how I can change my code so that I can actually display the value entered by the user in the toplevel page?

Many thanks<3

```
import Tkinter as tk


class Demo2:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.master, text = 'Quit', width = 25, command = self.close_windows)
        self.goButton = tk.Button(self.master, text = "Go",  command = self.window_one)
        global EnteredNumber
        self.EnteredNumber = tk.IntVar()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.master,textvariable=self.EnteredNumber)
        VertexNumber = self.EnteredNumber.get()
        self.goButton.pack()
        self.entry.pack()
        self.quitButton.pack()

    def close_windows(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def window_one(self):
        self.window_one = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Demo3(self.window_one)

class Demo3():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self.master, text=EnteredNumber)
        self.label = tk.Label(self.master, text="Hi")
        self.label.pack()
        self.label1.pack()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Demo2(root)
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Send the value of the `Entry` through to the `__init__` of `Demo3()`

First the changes to `window_one()`:

```
def window_one(self):
    enterednumber = self.entry.get()    # Grab the value in the Entry
    self.window_one = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
    self.app = Demo3(self.window_one, enterednumber)   # Send it to Demo3 as an argument
```

And then `Demo3()`

```
class Demo3():
    def __init__(self, master, enterednumber):    # Reconfigure __init__ to accept the new arg
        self.master = master
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self.master, text=enterednumber)
        self.label = tk.Label(self.master, text="Hi")
        self.label.pack()
        self.label1.pack()
```

Comment: OMG MAN YOU ARE A BOSS>

Comment: Thank you soooo much, Honestly, you made my day dude.